# Exclude transitive maven dependencies from generated war file

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

I am in the process of converting a monolithic legacy enterprise application to use maven instead of ant. I created a list of dependencies that ant was using for the builds and accordingly created a maven pom file to list those dependencies in.

The problem I'm currently facing is to try to include only the **direct dependencies** listed in the pom file, so that when an artifact is generated (war file in my case) only the direct dependencies are included in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the packaged war file for the maven project.

Example dependency used:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-all -->
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>     
        <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>     
        <version>1.16</version>     
        <type>pom</type> 
    </dependency>
```

Executing: mvn clean -U install

Results in downloading and packaging approximately 30 transitive dependencies just for batik-all-1.16.jar
(The transitive dependencies for batik-all can be seen listed here [batik-all-1.16.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-all/1.16/batik-all-1.16.pom))

After doing a lot of research, I came across this as a possible solution but it made no difference (didn't resolve my problem - still included all the transitive jars).

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-all -->
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>     
        <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>     
        <version>1.16</version>     
        <type>pom</type>
        <exclusions>         
            <exclusion>             
                <groupId>*</groupId>             
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>         
            </exclusion>     
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Anyone have an idea to resolve this issue?

I would prefer not to use the tag `<packagingExclusions>` available under the maven-war-plugin only because I would have to exclude almost 80 specific transitive dependencies total for all the dependencies I need for the project, from being copied into the generated WEB-INF/lib folder of the war file.

Using maven version: 3.3.9 and maven-war-plugin-pinned version: 3.2.2

Comment: How will your application function without the transitive dependencies?

Comment: Your `<exclusion>` is correct. It will exclude the transitive dependencies.

Comment: The biggest issue here is that most of the deps in batik-all are optional.. if I looked correctly only 2 are required... than the question is why do you have to exclude them? The other question is why using batik-all as a dependency and not the other package which are really needed? can you give more details on what you like to achieve?

Comment: @tgdavies - I have tested my application without the transitive jar files sitting in the WEB-INF/lib directory in the war file, and the app loaded successfully.

Comment: @JFabianMeier - Although '<exclusions>' is an option, it did not work for me. All the transitive jar files were still included in the resulting packaged war file.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I want to prevent any transitive jar files from being included in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the packaged war file. Although most of the batik-all dependecies have the optional=true flag set, they are still being downloaded during build time and copied into the war.

Comment: There must be some other error in your setup. Exclusions are what they say. They exclude transitive dependencies. If they are still there, you have an error somewhere else. Furthermore, optional dependencies are NOT downloaded and put into the WAR. This is also not true.

Comment: @JFabianMeier - What I seen while researching suggests that it should work however a full pom.xml file is never provided as an example to show how the wildcard exclusion will work in a pom that needs to generate a war file. The pom file I wrote isn't complex at all. It has dependencies listed and 1 plugin used (which is the maven-war-plugin). I am not sure if another plugin needs to be added to the pom in order for the exclusion wildcard to take into effect. Can you provide me an example of a full working pom file where the wild card exclusion are recognized when built?

Comment: Actually, I wonder why you have `<type>pom</type>` in your dependency. Maybe this causes the problem

Comment: @JFabianMeier - I've tried removing that and rebuilding, it didn't make a difference. Still say the transitive dependencies in my war file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this:

`batik-all` is a fat JAR. It already contains its dependencies. So you can only take it completely or leave it.

The alternative is to use other `batik` JARs that are not fat JARs.

Answer (score 0):

After considering everyone's response to my question I decided to take a step back in approaching the maven transitive dependencies for my project.

I removed all the dependencies, re-ran a `mvn clean install` command, and for all the build errors that returned I identified each and every dependency that would resolve the build errors to find out which dependency definitions were copying transitive jar files and applied the below specifically to those:

```
    <exclusions>      
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>       
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Running `mvn dependency:tree` also helped to visually see the relationships between various dependencies and their transitive dependencies.

Starting over from the beginning helped me identify which maven dependency definitions were truly causing the transitive jar files to be copied into the final deployable artifact for my project.